# Bar chart with custom labels in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone know how to create a bar chart with custom x-labels like this in Tikz with each bar colored differently (really don't care about the colors so long as alternate bars are colored the same and adjacent bars are colored differently)?

[image: barchart]

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. And what you try so far?

Comment: Thank you! I really haven't used Tikz before, so I really don't know where to start.

Comment: when i start to do something new, i usually first read instruction how to do this. `tikz` has very nice manual. it is worth to read its third part... anyway, for star see my answer below. mostly it is based on guessing, what you like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[ tikz,
                border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0mm,
    start chain = A going right,
bar/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, %
    fill=#1, minimum width=#2, 
    minimum height=1em, outer sep=0mm,
    node contents={}, on chain}
                    ]
\node[bar=blue!30/13mm];
\node[bar=red!30/21mm];
\node[bar=blue!30/13mm];
\node[bar=red!30/21mm];
    \draw[->]   ([xshift=-3mm]A-1.south west) -- ([xshift=7mm]A-4.south east);
    \draw[->]   ([yshift=-3mm]A-1.south west) -- ([yshift=7mm]A-1.north west);
\path   (A-1.south east) node[below] {$T$}
        (A-2.south east) node[below] {$T{+}L$}
        (A-3.south east) node[below] {$2T{+}L$}
        (A-4.south east) node[below] {$2T{+}2L$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.